# How would I ssh to Raspberry Pi from Android Device while it is connected to its hotspot?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, android, raspberry-pi

I have had a Raspberry Pi for a couple months now and it was my first time using Linux (so I'm still pretty new)

What I am trying to achieve here is being able to SSH to my Raspberry Pi (running Rasbian) from my android device (Galaxy S6 Edge running lollipop 5.1.1 (willing to root if necessary)) while it is connected to my androids hotspot. Or maybe the other way around where I connect to a hotspot created by the Raspberry Pi with my phone.

Would that be possible in any way? Perhaps how a Chromcast creates a hotspot for you to connect to in order to set it up. I find that to be a really neat concept, if only I am able to replicate that on a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to get a USB wifi adapter that is able to create a wifi network.  You would then connect to the wifi network, and ssh in.

Using a product such as [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003MTTJOY) and editing the settings ([example](http://www.amazon.com/forum/-/Tx3I2Y1OUH1M100/ref=ask_dp_dpmw_al_hza?asin=B003MTTJOY)) it will broadcast its own wifi network that the phone can connect to.  You can just treat the device as it was on a LAN and ssh to the correct IP.

Comment: Would it be that simple? I don't think my phone would recognize the Raspberry Pi as a device on the network but I might be mistaken. I have a USB wifi adapter I used on my computer before with a 3rd party program in order to make it into a hotspot so that shouldn't be an issue. But how would I go about making a hotspot on my Raspberry Pi?

Comment: See my update to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this as soon as I get my hands on the Raspberry Pi :)