# Make a wireless hotspot in Linux and then ssh to it when connected

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ssh, hotspot

I want my raspberry device to make its own hotspot when it boots up (Internet not needed), and then ssh to it.

**So the two questions I'm actually asking is...**

1. How do I create a hotspot in Linux?
2. Once connected, how do I successfully SSH to it?

After some digging around, I found [hotspotd](https://github.com/prahladyeri/hotspotd) that can make a hotspot and is pretty easy to configure. After creating the hotspot, I wasn't able to SSH.

I don't mind using an alternate program to make a hotspot, if it works better than this one.

My pi is running Debian.

*[This](https://superuser.com/q/1050897/573485) question has a slight similarity to my question, but I'd like more technical details and the answer remarks `ssh to the correct IP`. In my case, I'd like to assign the pi to a static ip, so please add on how to do that.*

Comment: After creating the hotspot did you successfully connect to it?

Comment: Yes, he was able to connect to it. @BaroudiSafwene

Comment: then typing route -n will give you the IP address of the router, to get a static IP every time the Raspberry pi boots up you want to edit /etc/network/interfaces or you can edit cmdline.txt and add  this ip=<client-ip>:<server-ip>:<gw-ip>:<netmask>:<hostname>:<device>:<autoconf>, eg: ip=192.168.1.200::192.168.1.1:255.255.255.0:rpi:eth0:off
.

Comment: Could you please answer my question, instead of commenting? I can't really follow your comment. @BaroudiSafwene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a hotspot from a raspberry pi and ssh to it:

1. sudo apt-get install hostapd
2. wget https://github.com/prahladyeri/hotspotd/raw/master/dist/hotspotd-latest.tar.gz
3. tar xvf hotspotd-latest.tar.gz
4. cd hotspo*
5. sudo python setup.py install
6. sudo hotspotd configure: Here, it will ask you for an IP address for the AP, type whatever you want( C class IP of course ), for example: 10.0.0.1
7. You must be running a dhcpd server to do so, enter:

   sudo dhcpd
8. Now you can connect to your access point =)
9. ssh pi@10.0.0.1
   now type your password.

Finally, if you want to get an AP everytime the pi boots up, here is a
[nice answer on how to run a script at start up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228304/how-do-i-run-a-script-at-start-up<br).
the script can just contain:

```
sudo hotspotd start
```

//Forget about my comment it's nonsense

EDIT: I am wrong about C class IPs, the truth is you should use private IPs:

- 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 (65,536 IP addresses)
- 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 (1,048,576 IP addresses)
- 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 (16,777,216 IP addresses)

Comment: What is a C class IP?